# Create nav during login process - FOSUserBUndle - Symfony

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I need your help.

I want to build my navigation during the login process and store it in session. Like that my navigation is load only one time and not at every action.

Why ? Because i need to build the nav with only the links that my current user logged has as right (ROLE)

The fact is i don't know how to access the user during the process of login in loginAction of an override SecurityController like this one...

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class SecurityController extends \FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController
{
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $response = parent::loginAction($request);

        $session = $request->getSession();

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //GET THE USER FROM $RESPONSE AND BUILD THE NAV WITH HIS ROLES IN A SESSION
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



        return  $response;// TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }

    public function logoutAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $session->clear();
        parent::logoutAction(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use KNPMenuBundle as a service. Inject token storage and check roles.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you'd create the menu on the fly from a service, injecting the `TokenStorageInterface` and `AuthorizationCheckerInterface` or some other mechanism (eg 3.4+ adds a simpler Security service) that allows fetching the `User` entity, and then from there checking the role, or other services

```
$token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();
if ($token) {
    $user = $token->getUser();
}
// $user->getCanonicalUsername() -- logged in username
// can also check what permissions a user has
if ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
     $menu->addChild('menu.admin', ['route' => 'admin_dashboard']);
}
```

Dealing with, and rebuilding the menus from the data in a large session store would probably also be at least as complex as an ordinary KNPMenuBuilder service.

Comment: I'm not an advanced dev on this topic... Could you try to explain me a bit or find me a work around to create a menu in $_SESSION with the current logged user just after he is logged ?

Comment: No, I will not teach you how to do things badly.The docs on https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/index.html and the code above (with `$this->tokenStorage = $this->container->get('security.token_storage');` to setup) are about 80% of the 'hard part' of everything you need to do - from the infrastructure required.